# The product of the first $k$ prime numbers except the prime number $2$ $\pm 2$ is a prime number?

Tags: prime-numbers

If $p_i$ is the $i^{th}$ prime number, let $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, k>2, P_k := \prod\limits_{i = 2}^{k}p_i.$ Then, at least one of $(P_k + 2, P_k -2)$ is a prime number.

I tested it up to $k = 10$.
Does it hold for all $k$, really?
Is what I'm proposing nonsense? It's just an idea that came to my mind. I am new here.

Comment: $k=10$ is really, really small.

Comment: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A002110) can save you some time.

Comment: As a general remark....there are lots and lots of small prime numbers.  If you only search amongst small numbers, you will get a lot of false patterns.  Any general claim, such as you are making, merits a deeper search. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BFactor%5B%28primorial%28n%29%2F2%29-2%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C20%7D%5D+and+Table%5BFactor%5B%28primorial%28n%29%2F2%29%2B2%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C20%7D%5D) is good enough in this case.

Comment: Thank you all. You are a very good community.

Comment: Unfortunately, your proposition is false. The first counterexample occurs when $k = 14,$ 
 since both $6541380665835015 - 2$ and $6541380665835015 + 2$ are composite numbers.

Comment: Note that $P_k\pm2$ won't have $p_1, p_2, \dots p_k$ as factors

Answer (score 2):

The conjecture is *false*.
For $k=14$, we get:

$
3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 \cdot 23 \cdot 29 \cdot 31 \cdot 37 \cdot 41 \cdot 43 = 6541380665835015
$

$
6541380665835015 - 2 = 6541380665835013 = 431 \cdot 125887 \cdot 120562229
$

$
6541380665835015 + 2 = 6541380665835017 = 613 \cdot 7841 \cdot 1360935349
$

Comment: you forgot to type $41$ -- I believe that makes it $k=14$ -- but the rest is correct, so $+1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, thanks for spotting this!